# $\frac{\tan^2(3x)}{1+\tan^2(3x)}+\frac{\tan^2(2x)}{1+\tan^2(2x)}+\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}=2$ has no solution?

Tags: trigonometry, proof-verification

$$\frac{\tan^2(3x)}{1+\tan^2(3x)}+\frac{\tan^2(2x)}{1+\tan^2(2x)}+\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}=2$$ if we simplify ,we have 
$$\sin^2(3x)+\sin^2(2x)+\sin^2(x)=2\\\frac{1-\cos(6x)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}=2\\
\cos(6x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(2x)=-1\\\cos(6x)+\cos(2x)=-(1+\cos(4x))\\2\cos(4x)\cos(2x)=-2\cos^2(2x)\\\begin{cases}\cos(2x)= 0 \to 2x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\\\cos(2x)=-\cos(4x)\to \begin{cases}\cos(2x)=-1\\\cos(2x)=\frac12\end{cases}\end{cases},$$ but all of the roots are not acceptable because ,the denominator of $\tan(3x) $ or $ \tan(2x) $ or$ \tan(x) $ going to be zero .
Is my work true ? 
  If draw the $f(x)=\frac{\tan^2(3x)}{1+\tan^2(3x)}+\frac{\tan^2(2x)}{1+\tan^2(2x)}+\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}$ and $g(x)=2$ by desmos ...we will see some roots $\frac{\pi}{6} ,\frac{\pi}{2} $ are recognizable ,but what about the other ?
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x9ikgkbyhp

Answer (score 1):

> `Suppose otherwise there exists` $x\in{\bf R}$ `such that`
>   $$
> \frac{\tan^2(3x)}{1+\tan^2(3x)}+\frac{\tan^2(2x)}{1+\tan^2(2x)}+\frac{\tan^2(x)}{1+\tan^2(x)}=2.
> $$ 
>   If we simplify `(using the formula` $\sin^2a+\cos^2a=1$ `for each term)`, we have 
>   $$\sin^2(3x)+\sin^2(2x)+\sin^2(x)=2\\
> \Rightarrow \frac{1-\cos(6x)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(4x)}{2}+\frac{1-\cos(2x)}{2}=2\\
> \Rightarrow
> \cos(6x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(2x)=-1\\
> \Rightarrow\cos(6x)+\cos(2x)=-(1+\cos(4x))$$
>   `which implies that (this step is too quick for me, I don't see why (*) is obviously true.)`
>   $$
> 2\cos(4x)\cos(2x)=-2\cos^2(2x)\tag{*}
> $$
>   $$\tag{**}
> \begin{cases}
> \cos(2x)= 0 \to 2x=\pm\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi\\
> \cos(2x)=-\cos(4x)\to \begin{cases}\cos(2x)=-1\\
> \cos(2x)=\frac12
> \end{cases}
> \end{cases},
> $$ 
>   `(Too quick. Why does` $\cos(2x)=-\cos(4x)$ `imply the values you claim in (**)?)`
>   but all of the roots are not acceptable because, the denominator of $\tan(3x) $ or $ \tan(2x) $ or $\tan(x) $ going to be zero. `($\cos(2x)=0$ certainly gives a contradiction. How do` $-1$ `or` $1/2$ `do so?)`

---

Is my work true? `(Unclear. You don't have obvious logic mistakes but proof for several important places is missing.)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are right and our equation has no solutions.

"Roots" $a$ which you see they are because $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\left(\frac{\tan^23x}{1+\tan^23x}+\frac{\tan^22x}{1+\tan^22x}+\frac{\tan^2x}{1+\tan^2x}\right)=2.$$
It follows from your solution, but the domain says that they are not roots.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that whoever has produced this problem has constructed a form for $sin^2(x)$ which is artificial for the purpose of the puzzle.

It therefore *seems* like there is a problem.

But there is not because the *everywhere* in $\mathbb{R}$ the expression involving $tan(x)$ is always going to reduce to $sin^2(x)$.

The artificiality of using $tan(x)$ is a red herring.

It would be like defining $x$ as $\frac {x^2}{x}$ and then claiming there was a singular point at $x=0$ (which there is not).